# How to handle error scenarios in Csv file download with web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following code to post data to my api controller

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = '/api/reportsapi/exportToCsv';
form.method = 'POST';
form.style.display = 'none';
for (i in data) {
    if (data[i] != "") {
        var inputElement = document.createElement('textarea');
        inputElement.name = i;
        inputElement.value = data[i];
        form.appendChild(inputElement);
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

and my api controller returns a `HttpResponseMessage`

```
var csvValidRequestResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(csvReport.Data) };
csvValidRequestResult.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/comma-separated-values");
csvValidRequestResult.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = csvReport.FileName };
return csvValidRequestResult;
```

all this works fine. A file with data is downloaded when the above scripts hits the controller.

But the problem arises if there is any server side exception, in that case the page gets redirected to the the form's api url.

Is there something I can do to get to know of the error and act accordingly on the client side ?

Comment: why not make an ajax call??